# Trying to achieve full resolution on an LG ultrawide monitor

Tags: windows-10, display

TLDR: I want to use my LG ultrawide monitor (34BN670) to full 2560x1080 (21:9) resolution with my Windows 10 PC.

In my Windows PC under (Right Click on Desktop) ==> Display ==> Settings a resolution of 1680x1050 is recommended and somehow "works" but parts of my PC are blank as a 16:10 ratio cannot fill my 21:9 monitor. I want to use the 2560x1080 resolution. If I change the resolution to 2560x1080, catastrophes happen. The resolution is catastrophic and looks super strange. The "actual" resolution is then much worse. How can I properly switch to a resolution of 2560x1080?

My PC only has a VGA and a DVI output no HDMI output! Do I need an HDMI output or a display port output?

What I tried so far:

- change resolution under (Right Click on Desktop) ==> Display ==> Settings
  for many different resolutions
- restart PC, restart monitor, etc.
- change the cable from DVI to VGA etc.

The specifications of my system:

- Monitor: LG Ultrawide Full HD Monitor
- Model NR: 34BN670

PC:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8300 Eight-Core Processor, 3,3 GHZ
- Graphics Card: ATI Radeon 3000

Comment: You either need a "dual link" DVI cable, or your need your computer to have a dual-link output. Single link DVI is effectively limited to 1920x1200. Dual link is the same connector but more pins.